# SaveFileDialog - how to get preselected directory for saving files without opening dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

How to get directory which will would be selected on save file dialog open? I suppose it must be some value saved in Windows maybe per application because same value will be used between different application runs. Plus differs between different applications.

I would like to save file on location which was selected in previous application run without need to open `SaveFileDialog`. And I would like to avoid any value storing by myself.

Comment: What does "preselected" mean?  Preselected by what or whom?  When?

Comment: When dialog is opened, some value is used by dialog to show folder to save file into. I am interested in that value. How to obtain it without opening dialog and do save manually

Comment: Set the InitialDirectory property to encourage the user to save it to a particular folder.  This isn't normally necessary btw, the OS remembers where the dialog was last used.  Hard to guess why you didn't see that when you tested.

Comment: Hans, currently I use same solution you propose. But this is not fully OK for newly run application. In my current code I am setting InitialDirectory to Documents directory. Thus directory for file saving may vary from last time application is run. Information about last save file location is the only one I need right now. I would like to avoid saving that value to some config file since I suppose it should be somewhere accessible :-)

Answer (score 0):

FileDialog instances keep last directory within process execution in InitialDirectory property.

You can keep default path within runnings by using settings for example.

In the solution explorer, go to Properties section and double-click on Settings.settings: you can add here a parameter named "DefaultDirectory" for example (string).

And use it in code:

```
// Initialize if default path is empty (check at app startup)
Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectory = "C:\\Folder";

// Set the default path (in Forms.Loaded or elsewhere)
SomeDialog.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectory;
```

EDIT: my answer to the question is in fact to use a value in the registry shared across the apps (or in a file in a shared system or user folder).

Comment: I know I could use Settings for storing that value, but I wonder whether that value can be accessible just after plain application start without actual storing it anywhere by myself.

Comment: If you don't store the value between process sessions (any file or settings file, registry, memory or other), you can't retreive it.

Comment: Windows have this value somewhere stored, because if I run my application again directory for saving file stays same as last time. Therefore that value is not application-run oriented by more application oriented. So I wonder whether it can be obtained somehow.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I don't know. You can't use app settings for what you want to do. Storing the last processed directory shared across multiple apps in registry may be fine.